# Alembic bulk_insert to table with schema

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

I'm looking at the example at [bulk_insert](https://alembic.readthedocs.org/en/rel_0_1/ops.html#alembic.op.bulk_insert).

```
# Create an ad-hoc table to use for the insert statement.
accounts_table = table('account',
    column('id', Integer),
    column('name', String),
    column('create_date', Date)
)
```

I would like to `bulk insert` to a specific schema called `kpi` but I can't figure out how to do it. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer I've found so far is to use the sqlalchemy function instead like below:

```
accounts_table = sa.Table('accounts_table', sa.MetaData(),
    sa.Column('id', sa.Integer),
    sa.Column('name', sa.String(100)),
    sa.Column('create_date', sa.Date),
    schema='phone'
)
```